# number of query values and destination fields are not the same

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, insert-into

This is what I have for the Add Event.

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tblMatchBook ([Patron], [Staff], [TimeReceived], [SurveyLink], [DateFinished], [BookTitles]) " & _
" Values('" & Me.ddBarcode & "," & Me.ddStaff & "," & Me.txtRDate & "," & Me.txtLink & "," & "" & "," & "" & "')"
```

I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score -2):

```
insert into Main values (28494,1,False,'Buto-asma  Sirop' , 'Buto-asma  Sirop', 3.99 , 'Syrup', 'ispani', ' ', ' ',0, '1',4988 )
```

Comment: Please add some explanatory text to your answer

Comment: This statement does in no single way relate to the question. It seem to relate to your now deleted answer that asked a new question which you shouldn't do in an answer box. Remember we are not a forum. I suggest you take the [tour] and revisit [ask] and maybe take some time to read the other material in the [help]. Good luck!